# EMR Spark Cluster No space left on device 5000 partitions

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

When we tried to run our Spark Job which is processing 2gb and 10 gb files. I am getting the Error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2003 in stage 32.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2003.0 in stage 32.0 (TID 33046, localhost, executor driver): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/tmp/blockmgr-13430cd7-0455-4sfgs-a98f-7f96e0252471/13/temp_shuffle_e680c565-f17a-47cb-9ef9-29cdcf14e50f (No space left on device)
```

We are running this by repartitioning the two DataFrames to 5000 ( we tried with 100, 1000 and ran into the same issue).

Here are some Spark Configurations we are using.

INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 38.1 GB

```
spark.executor.memory] =12G
spark.driver.memory =64G
spark.executor.cores =4
```

We are attaching a 100BG EBS Volume when we create the instances ( we have 5 node cluster which is dynamically created from java aws sdk)

Not sure why we are running out of space when we are dealing with files are which are no bigger than 20gb at most.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was setting the root volume.

I had to change the way i am creating the cluster and now i am assigning EBS Volumes to each instance in the cluster.

```
private InstanceFleetConfig getInstanceFleetConfig(String instanceType,InstanceFleetType instanceFleetType,int onDemandCapacity) {
        InstanceFleetConfig masterInstanceConfig = new InstanceFleetConfig();
        masterInstanceConfig.setInstanceFleetType(instanceFleetType);
        masterInstanceConfig.setTargetOnDemandCapacity(onDemandCapacity);

        InstanceTypeConfig instanceTypeConfig = new InstanceTypeConfig();
        instanceTypeConfig.setInstanceType(instanceType);

        EbsConfiguration ebsConfiguration = new EbsConfiguration();
        EbsBlockDeviceConfig ebsBDConfig = new EbsBlockDeviceConfig();
        // Setting the Volume Size to 100GB
        ebsBDConfig.setVolumeSpecification(new VolumeSpecification().withSizeInGB(100).withVolumeType(VolumeType.Gp2.toString()));

        List<EbsBlockDeviceConfig> ebsBlockDeviceConfigs = new ArrayList<EbsBlockDeviceConfig>();
        ebsBlockDeviceConfigs.add(ebsBDConfig);

        ebsConfiguration.setEbsBlockDeviceConfigs(ebsBlockDeviceConfigs);

        instanceTypeConfig.setEbsConfiguration(ebsConfiguration);

        List<InstanceTypeConfig> instanceTypeConfigs = new ArrayList<InstanceTypeConfig>();
        instanceTypeConfigs.add(instanceTypeConfig);

        masterInstanceConfig.setInstanceTypeConfigs(instanceTypeConfigs);

        return masterInstanceConfig;
    }
```